# How to change the text of the button from TextBox

Tags: c#

[image: form1]

Hi i have Form1 that look like this and i need to change the buttons Text from the textbox. Can someone help me.

Is like this: I have 30 students and every student name is the Text for a button I need to be able to change there name from 1 textbox and 1button like in the picture where I have 30 buttons for student names and 1 textbox and 1 button to change their name.Any button should be able to receive a new name I think the change name like this : when I press the student name button his text well be passed to the textbox and a label then change the name in the textbox the label well stay with the old name then press the change name button ( if label.text is like student button.text then textbox.text replace student button.text) or something like this

Comment: `button1.Text = textBox1.Text;`

Comment: Hi for all buttons and every button has a different name

Comment: Does the button text always end with number as well as the textbox names; do they align with each other?

Comment: You left a lot of details out of your question.

Comment: `this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ForEach(butt => butt.Text = textBox1.Text);` not sure about syntax, but basically getting all buttons and then change their text. We can help more, but as mentioned, much information and details have been left out.

Comment: No the Text is like student names and I don't want to have a textbox and change text button for every student button just one textbox and one button to change all buttons text from it

Comment: Is like this: I have 30 students and every student name is the Text for a button I need to be able to change there name from 1 textbox and 1button like in the picture where I have 30 buttons for student names and 1 textbox and 1 button to change their name

Comment: Please update your question with the details rather than posting them in the comments. That will help get your question upvoted and everyone will see what you're asking.

Comment: How would you know which button should receive the new name? I think you may need to do a little more UI design work up front before you start the implementation here.

Comment: Presumably pressing a student name button brings up details about that student? In any case, a "Student Details" form would probably be the best place to change the student's name. Then when you exit from the details back to this form, the button text will be updated from the data source.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described the `Student` class and how the names are being stored/updated in the backend.

Comment: Any button should be able to receive a new name I think the change name like this : when I press the student name button his text well be passed to the textbox and a label then change the name in the textbox the label well stay with the old name then press the change name button ( if label.text = student button.text then textbox.text replace student button.text) or something like this

Comment: The student names well be stored in Application settings that is my plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi this is the solution to my problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Button> _buttons;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _buttons = Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();

        }

        private void ChangeTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var result = _buttons.FirstOrDefault(button => button.Text == "button2");

            if (result == null) return;
            result.Text = label1.Text;

       }
    }
}
```